# Precedence of AND and OR into an IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement, logic, conditional-statements

Are equivalents these statements?

```
if ($a || $b && $c)
{
    // ...
}

if (($a || $b) && $c)
{
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT**

What a beating! But worth it... THX to all!

Comment: please test this in your localhost

Comment: actually you should avoid to write like your first line because it's ambigous

Comment: I can read manuals but logic is not so easy to understand. That's why ask, It's sure that some one can give some short and useful answer.

Comment: @yes123 that's the idea here, use precedence instead parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: **NO**. They're not equivalent.

Check out [the PHP Operator Precedence table](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). It clearly lists `&&` before `||`.

See it here in action: http://viper-7.com/cPycas

---

If you want to use precedence instead of parenthesis, you can use the more verbose `AND`:

```
if ($a || $b AND $c)
{
    // ...
}
```

[Here's the demo](http://viper-7.com/39rmzT), but I'd advise you against it, since it's not as clear as parenthesis.

Comment: Stop it smart guy. The manual don't say how understand logic. I't s a simple question that always come to collation, Sure that not only to me..

Comment: @NomikOS - I'm sorry if I was a bit harsh on you, but the table is very easy to read (once you get the hang of it). Any operator that appears higher up in the table has precedence over anything below it.

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` has higher precedence than the `||`, so no, they're not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

No. In PHP, `($a || $b && $c)` is evaluated as: `($a || ($b && $c))`

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 1):

Consider **AND** as multiplication, **OR** as addition, you'll get the truthiness as well as the priority.

```
$a = 1; 
$b = 0;
$c = 0;

if ($a + $b * $c)
{
    // ...
}

if (($a +  $b) * $c)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

&& has precedence over ||. [Operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: @downvoter possibly check the timestamp of my (unedited) comment above. I struggle to compete with citations on my tab.